# What does it mean to "own" a feeling?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I cam across this below sentence in [this](http://goodvibeblog.com/bashar-how-to-change-beliefs/) website:

> ***When you feel an idea you don’t prefer (like fear, self doubt, sorrow, sadness, etc.) the first thing is not to ignore or suppress
>   it, but to feel it fully. Own it.***

So in this above sentence what does the author mean by saying feel or own the emotion ( the emotions of fear, self doubt, sorrow, sadness, etc.)?

Comment: Related: [What Does “Own It” Really Mean?](http://www.neverwhatyouthink.com/what-does-own-it-really-mean/)

Comment: Note also that "don't prefer" is a strange way to express the intention here, which is presumably something like "dislike." The author may not be fluent in English.

Comment: @TimLymington Well, yes and no.  The google tells me that the OP's quote belong to "Bashar", about whom below: *Darryl Anka, an artist and UFO researcher, is also acclaimed internationally as the channel of Bashar, an extraterrestrial being, known for his practical teachings on moving beyond limitations. Darryl lives in southern California.*

Comment: @deadrat: that looks to me like "yes and yes". Southern California is well-known for many things, but not grammatical exactitude. And Bashar may be both wise and practical, but can hardly be a native speaker of English.

Comment: @TimLymington I meant *yes* if you think the author is Anka and *no* if you think the author is Bashar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that instead of being **passively** affected by an emotion, you have to make it yours. You have to fully integrate it into your being, and not be a **slave** of it. **Introspection** is a concept that is quite connected to this one too.

This is a rather philosophical matter so we won't discuss about it too much on this section, but an **[Own your emotions](https://www.google.fr/?ion=1&espv=2#q=own%20your%20emotions)** Google search should give you some results to start with.

Comment: Thank You. So when you say `you have to make it yours`, do you mean we have to wallow in that feeling? Thanks.

Comment: @CSinha: More like acknowledge it, with its causes and its consequences.